# Visual Studio Project Template - TemplateContent Populated by Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio Project Template but I don't wish to manually populate the TemplateContent section. Ideally it would fire off a C# script when it tries to create the template's zip file. I was wondering if there are any hooks built in to allow you to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I'm trying to create a Visual Studio Project Template but I don't wish to manually populate the TemplateContent section. Ideally it would fire off a C# script when it tries to create the template's zip file. I was wondering if there are any hooks built in to allow you to do this?

As far as I know, Microsoft does not provide related API to handle TemplateContent section, but we know that TemplateContent section is a node of XML. We could populate the TemplateContent section by using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to use a Pre-Build event to fire off a Powershell script which will then use LINQ to XML to replace the TemplateContent section.